# Automated email generation not resolving multiple recipients

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba, outlook-2007

I have a VBA script which creates & saves Draft emails.  To add recipients, it pulls a string from a linked Excel table and adds that to the Recipients object.

For emails with single recipients, this works like a charm.  All the user needs to do is open the draft, spend 5 seconds looking it over, and hit Send.

The problem occurs with several contacts at once (e.g. "a@aol.com; b@aol.com; c@aol.com").  When the user hits Send, Outlook will pop up a Check Names dialogue with no suggestions. The user can get around this by clicking on the To field and entering a dummy semicolon to trigger the auto resolve.  I'd like to avoid this since this process creates well over a hundred emails at a time which need to be individually reviewed.

Looking around on the net, I've found and tried Recipients.ResolveAll which returns false.  I suspect the reason is that Outlook is trying to resolve the entire string of recipients at once and not individually.  So my question is: how do I get Outlook to stop displaying this Check Names dialogue?  Do I need to loop thru my email string and parse out the individual emails?

```
Sub CreateEmail(id as Integer)
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim ObjMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim CurrentRecipient As Outlook.Recipient

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ObjMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set Recipients = ObjMail.Recipients

    Dim StrEmailTo As String
    StrEmailTo = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
        "Select [Emails] from LU_Contacts where id=" & id & ";").Fields(0)

    Set CurrentRecipient = Recipients.Add(StrConv(StrEmailTo, 3))
    CurrentRecipient.Type = olTo
    ...

    Objmail.Save
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Recipients.Add` takes a single email address.

If you wish to have multiple recipients, call `Recipients.Add` for each one.

If your string is returned in a `;` delimited format, then something like:

```
dim EmailList as variant
dim NumEmails as long
dim AddEmailLoop as long

EmailList=split(StrEmailTo,";")
NumEmails=UBound(EmailList)

For AddEmailLoop=0 to NumEmails
    Recipients.add(EmailList(AddEmailLoop))
next
```

should allow you to add the entire list

Comment: Looks promising.  I'll try it out and let you know.