# Keep formatting of Outlook signature when creating mail

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook-2007

I copied the whole block of code from [How can I use Outlook to send email to multiple recipients in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985261/excel-vba-email-using-outlook-to-multiple-recipients) and added a signature at the end of the email message.

```
With OutMail
    .Display
End With
    Signature = OutMail.Body
With OutMail
    .To = sTo
    .CC = sCC
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Worksheets("MassEmail").Range("A2") & " WW" & Worksheets("MassEmail").Range("B1")
    sHTML = "<HTML><BODY><FONT face=""Calibri, Arial"">"
    sHTML = sHTML & "<p style=""font-size:11pt"">Hi,</p>"
    sHTML = sHTML & "<p style=""font-size:11pt"">Here is the RMA list WW" & Worksheets("MassEmail").Range("B1") & ".  Please review.</p>"
    sHTML = sHTML & "<pre style=""font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,Arial"">     Total: </pre>"
    .HTMLBody = sHTML & Signature
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</FONT></BODY></HTML>"
End With
```

This is how the signature should look.
[image: Original signature]

The output is ok except the signature.
[image: HTMLbody]

I tried changing .htmlbody to .body, but results are worse.

The output with .body.
[image: Body]

I'm using Excel/Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the format of the messaage to RichText or HTMLFormat

something like **olFormatHTML** or **olFormatRichText**

then use *MailItem.HTMLBody="...."*

there is more information on **VBA MVP Legend Ron De Bruin**'s website

[Example Code for sending mail from Excel](http://www.rondebruin.nl/sendmail.htm)

Comment: I have added links to Ron De Bruins website, and [here is another link with detail on using HTMLBody](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/folder3/mail4.htm)