# VBA to forward an email

Tags: vba, email, outlook, forward

I have designed a macro to forward an email. The below code drafts a forward email, adds some information in the body, retains the original content at the bottom of the email. But the only problem is, when the macro attempts to forward the email, the original format is getting lost.

Also, by default, it displays my email id as From Address. Instead, it should be "ops@ccorp.com". Could you please help me?

```
Sub Forward_Email()
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMsg = objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set objForward = objMsg.Forward
objForward.Recipients.Add "someone@example.com"
objForward.CC = "eg1@example.com"
objOrignialBody = objForward.Body
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"C:\Users\desktop\Email Distribution Control File.xlsx"
Sheets("Incorrect Device Type").Select
EmailLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
Cells.Find(What:="Subject", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
BodyofEmail = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
For emailrange = 6 To EmailLastRow - 1
If ActiveCell.Row > EmailLastRow Then
GoTo DraftEmail
Else
End If
BodyofEmail = BodyofEmail & vbCrLf & ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next emailrange
DraftEmail:
objForward.Display
objForward.Body = BodyofEmail & vbCr & vbCr & vbCr & objOrignialBody
```

Comment: What format is getting lost? The email's format (i.e., as Rich Text vs. HTML vs. Plain Text), or the Excel cell's format (which you aren't capturing in this code)?

Comment: Hi David, The HTML format is getting lost. Does this information help you?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758300/excel-vba-formatting-of-outlook-signature-is-gone

Comment: The html body is property HtmlBody which you are not setting.  Note that there is no automatic conversion of Excel formatting if you copy a cell.  You have to create the html you write to HtmlBody or use PublishObjects if you are happy with crap html.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to the end of your code to send the email on behalf off opsccorp@com:

```
objforward.SentOnBehalfOfName = "ops@ccorp.com"
```