# Outlook VBA, cut email address from subject and place it as recipient, then forward the message

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to find a VBA code Outlook email forwarder that will grab (and remove) an email address from Subject field. Then add the email address as recipient and forward the message with attachments.

I'll try to demonstrate and example:

---

**Arriving email:**

From: *alias@domain.com*

Subject: *xyz@domain.com LHV Calculation ... 0001*

(Note that "...0001" is variable, so everything after "LHV..." should remain the same)

---

**Forwarded email:**

To: *xyz@domain.com*

Subject: *LHV Calculation ... 0001*

---

Nothing else should not be changed in the header or the body of the message. (end recipient of the mail can't see it has been forwarded from other mail).

I'm very new to VBA coding and I hope someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples of forwarding email on t'interweb; such as [VBA to forward an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361769/vba-to-forward-an-email)

There are also plenty of examples of string manipulation. If the format of the subject is consistent then searching for the first space in the string will give you the length of the email address.

```
oSubj = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Subject
'Take the forward-an-email example and adjust to your needs
objForward.Recipients.Add = Left(oSubj, InStr(1, oSubj, " "))
```

will only work on an open message plus you'd need further checks in case the subject starts with RE: or FWD: etc.