# multiple recipients email mismatch in VBA

Tags: vba, email, excel

I am trying to add multiple recipients' emails that are on a range of cells.

I am able to select the range of emails on the sheet.

However, I kept getting this **mismatch error** and I have no idea how to solve it.

I have been looking around for solutions and did the same steps.

Please pardon me, i am new to VBA.
I would very much appreciate your help.
My code is below,

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        Dim olapp As Object
        Dim olmail As Object
        Dim recip As String


    lastr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    'this is for the range of data to be copied on the body but have yet to do it

    lastr2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row


        recip = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3:G" & lastr2).Value 
        'mismatch after this step

        Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(0)

        With MItem
         .to = recip
         .Subject = "hello"
         .Body = "whats up"
         .display
         End With
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14985344/1698517)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign an array (a range of multiple cells is an Array) to a string variable. WIthout testing, I *know* you can resolve this with a `For Each` loop, as Jaycal's comment suggested:

```
Dim cl as Range
For each cl in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3:G" & lastr2).Cells
    recip = recip & ";" & cl.Value    
Next
```

But you could simplify by using the [string `Join` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164507%28v=office.10%29.aspx).  The `Join` function effectively performs this loop on an array of strings, so it saves you an unnecessary loop.  I modify to use a range variable for legibility:

```
Dim sendRange as Range
Set sendRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3:G" & lastr2)
recip = Join(Application.Transpose(sendRange.Value), ";")
```

Whichever method you use, you will be able to use the same `With` block.

```
    With MItem
     .to = recip
     .Subject = "hello"
     .Body = "whats up"
     .display
     End With
```