# mismatch in putting a specific range into body of email

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, range

I am trying to insert a range of specific cells into the body of my email

i am able to specify the range of cells i want, however, i kept getting mismatch error again.

I previously have a rather similar problem for my recipients variable too and it has been solved, thanks to David Zemens

- [multiple recipients email mismatch in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955681/multiple-recipients-email-mismatch-in-vba)

PS: I really have not much knowledge about this email automation on outlook

I would appreciate your help. My code is below

```
Dim A As New Outlook.Application
Dim B As MailItem
Dim expireditems As Range
Dim addresses As String
Dim addressesrange As Range
Dim msg As String

Set expireditems = Nothing

Set A = New Outlook.Application
Set B = A.CreateItem(olMailItem)

LastR5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expired").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastR6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expired").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

For Each addressesrange In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expired").Range("G3:G" & LastR6).Cells
 addresses = addresses & ";" & addressesrange.Value
Next

Set expireditems = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expired").Range("A2:E" & LastR5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If expireditems Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There are no expired items today"
        Exit Sub
    End If

msg = "Please remove the listed expired items." & vbCr & expireditems
'MISMATCH HERE AGAIN


With B
    .To = addresses
    .Subject = "Attention: Expired Items"
    .Body = msg
    .Importance = olImportanceHigh 'High importance
    .Display
End With
```

If possible i like to know why as well.

Answer (score 2):

> i am able to specify the range of cells i want, however, i kept getting mismatch error again.
>
> msg = "Please remove the listed expired items." & vbCr & expireditems
>
> 'MISMATCH HERE AGAIN

`expireditems` is defined as a Range. You cannot use it in a string like that.

Change the line

`msg = "Please remove the listed expired items." & vbCr & expireditems`

to

`msg = "Please remove the listed expired items." & vbCr & expireditems.Address`

Also if you want to import the range into the email body then you might also want to look at Ron's article on [RangetoHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519602%28v=office.11%29)

Comment: hi Siddharth Rout, i have input what you edited but after the message "please remove the listed expired items" it did not show an array of table, just "$A$2:$E$3". I have looked into Ron's article but i believe mine is just a simple putting a table of data into the email?

Comment: Your question was about `Mismatch` which I answered :) Now regarding your next question of putting the `table of data into the email`, you could also check the same link for `Mailing a Range or Selection in the Body of an E-Mail Message`

Comment: I have seen that coding before. I am using outlook to mail my item and, the coding had this part ".HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)" so i felt doubtful and thought maybe it does not apply to outlook because HTML is more for internet browsers right? i am new to all these so i would appreciate your kind explaination :)

Comment: No. Outlooks body can take 3 formats - HTML, Plain text and Rich Text. Sure I can explain things but which part are you stuck with? Ron has already covered everything in that link...

Comment: haha i just needed the explanation on the HTML part. I'll try it out at work first thing in the morning! thanks a lot!