# multiple recipients in email but send mail through loop

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

```
For i = LBound(reviewer_names) To UBound(reviewer_names)
        reviwer_strg = reviewer_names(i)
        assigned_to_strg = assigned_to_names(LBound(assigned_to_names))
        For j = 6 To 15
            st1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("H" & j).Value
            If (reviwer_strg = st1) Then
                reviewer_email_id = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("I" & j).Value
                Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                olMail.To = reviewer_email_id
                olMail.Recipients.Add (reviewer_email_id)
                olMail.Subject = "Task for Review;" & client_name & ";" & title
                str1 = "Dear " & reviewer & ", " & "<br>" & "Please see the following for review." & "<br>"
                str2 = "Task : " & title & "<br>" & "Client Name : " & client_name & "<br>" & "Due Date : " & due_date & "<br><br>"

                str3 = "Document Location : " & "<a href=""" & document_location & """>" & document_location & "</a>" & "<br>"

                str4 = "Backup Location : " & "<a href=""" & backup_location & """>" & backup_location & "</a>" & "<br><br>"
                str5 = "Awaiting your Feedback." & "<br>" & "Regards, " & "<br>" & assigned_to_strg
                olMail.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>" & str1 & str2 & str3 & str4 & str5 & "</BODY>"
                olMail.Send
            End If
        Next
    Next i
```

I am sending emails by extracting email-ids from a column in excel, by comparing the names entered in a cell.

Cells from where I am extracting the names.
[image]

"Assigned to" and "Reviewer" Columns which is used to compare the names entered in the cells and the names in the columns. from this I am picking up the corresponding email id and sending mail.
[image]

The emails that I am sending are through loops. Hence everytime a mail is sent, the `olMail.To` picks up a single email id, and sends email to all the reviewers it matches in the column. But the recipients shows only the email id of the current recipient. I want to show all the email ids to which the email is sent, but send emails to each reviewer. ( Like mail to multiple addresses). The problem is that if I add all the email ids that are matched, in `olMail.To`, it gives me an error since it cannot contain more than one email id at a time.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to review the documentation for any procedures you're using with which you aren't completely familiar.

---

> The [`To` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-to-property-outlook) returns or sets a semicolon-delimited String list of display names for the To recipients for the Outlook item. This property contains the display names only. The To property corresponds to the MAPI property `PidTagDisplayTo`. The [`Recipients`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipients-object-outlook) collection should be used to modify this property.

<sup>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-to-property-outlook))</sup>

> The [`Recipients`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipients-object-outlook) collection contains a collection of [`Recipient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipient-object-outlook) objects for an Outlook item.  Use the [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/recipients-add-method-outlook) method to create a new [Recipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipient-object-outlook) object and add it to the Recipients object.

<sup>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipients-object-outlook))</sup>

---

> ### Example:
>
> ```
> ToAddress = "test@test.com"
> ToAddress1 = "test1@test.com"
> ToAddress2 = "test@test.com"
> MessageSubject = "It works!."
> Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
> Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
> newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
> newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
> newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress1)
> newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress2)
> newMail.Send
> ```

<sup>([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082087/8112776))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution code in case someone needs it :

```
For i = LBound(reviewer_names) To UBound(reviewer_names) - 1
        reviwer_strg = reviewer_names(i)
        assigned_to_strg = assigned_to_names(LBound(assigned_to_names))
        For j = 6 To 15
            st1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("H" & j).Value
            If (reviwer_strg = st1) Then
                reviewer_email_id = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("I" & j).Value
                Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

                olMail.Subject = "Task for Review;" & client_name & ";" & title
                str1 = "Dear " & reviewer & ", " & "<br>" & "Please see the following for review." & "<br>"
                str2 = "Task : " & title & "<br>" & "Client Name : " & client_name & "<br>" & "Due Date : " & due_date & "<br><br>"
                str3 = "Document Location : " & "<a href=""" & document_location & """>" & document_location & "</a>" & "<br>"
                str4 = "Backup Location : " & "<a href=""" & backup_location & """>" & backup_location & "</a>" & "<br><br>"
                str5 = "Awaiting your Feedback." & "<br>" & "Regards, " & "<br>" & assigned_to_strg
                olMail.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>" & str1 & str2 & str3 & str4 & str5 & "</BODY>"

                For x = LBound(reviewer_names) To UBound(reviewer_names)
                    recipient_strg = reviewer_names(x)
                    Debug.Print x & reviewer_names(x)
                    For y = 6 To 15
                        st2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("H" & y).Value
                        If (recipient_strg = st2) Then
                            recipient_email_id = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("I" & y).Value
                            olMail.Recipients.Add (recipient_email_id)
                        End If
                    Next y
                Next x
              olMail.Send
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Email has been sent !!!")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the example below.  I think this will do all you want, and more.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

See the link below for more details.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm