# Send emails to list and format font

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to do 2 things in VBA Excel. 1. Send emails to a list of recipients (can only send 1 now) 2. Add font formatting to specific figures

The file I'm creating uses a textbox to create the email body that is then sent out to the email addresses. Each having different figures. When I run the macro only 1 email name is pulled I was hoping to be able to pull up to 4 per email. Also I just need to add font changes to specific figures like MTDRev or LMRev.

```
Sub send_mass_email()

Dim i As Integer
Dim name, Email, Email2, Email3, GMEmail, body, subject, MTDRev, LMRev, SYSRevGrowth, MTDNMU, LMNMU, NMUChange, MTDLeads, LMLeads, LeadsChange, OSAvg, AvgNMU, AvgActivityMTD As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text

i = 2
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    
name = Range("A2").Value
Email = Range("B2").Value
Email2 = Range("C2").Value
Email3 = Range("D2").Value
GMEmail = Range("E2").Value
body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
subject = Range("F2").Value
MTDRev = Range("G2").Value
LMRev = Range("H2").Value
SYSRevGrowth = Range("I2").Value
MTDNMU = Range("J2").Value
LMNMU = Range("K2").Value
NMUChange = Range("L2").Value
MTDLeads = Range("M2").Value
LMLeads = Range("N2").Value
LeadsChange = Range("O2").Value
OSAvg = Range("P2").Value
AvgNMU = Range("Q2").Value
AvgActivityMTD = Range("R2").Value

body = Replace(body, "A2", name)
body = Replace(body, "G2", MTDRev)
body = Replace(body, "H2", LMRev)
body = Replace(body, "I2", SYSRevGrowth)
body = Replace(body, "J2", MTDNMU)
body = Replace(body, "K2", LMNMU)
body = Replace(body, "L2", NMUChange)
body = Replace(body, "M2", MTDLeads)
body = Replace(body, "N2", LMLeads)
body = Replace(body, "O2", LeadsChange)
body = Replace(body, "P2", OSAvg)
body = Replace(body, "Q2", AvgNMU)
body = Replace(body, "R2", AvgActivityMTD)
body = Replace(body, "W2", Title)
body = Replace(body, "X2", Date)
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
     .to = Email
     .to = Email2
     .to = Email3
     .to = GMEmail
     .subject = subject
     .body = body
     '.Attachments.Add ("") 'You can add files here
     .Display
     '.Send

    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text 'reset body text
    
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
```

Comment: What have you tried adding to the code to implement your idea? Where did you run into trouble with it? Please include that in your question.

Comment: What's the purpose of `i` here?  You don't seem to use it within the loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985261/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-addresses-stored-in-excel for adding multiple recipients.

Comment: I've tried changing the ".to = Email" to B2:H2 to include the extra email addresses. I don't really know VBA that well to be honest. The issue is every time I run the macro, only 1 email address is pulled. from B2, I need it to pull multiple B2:H2, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer for Multiple Email Recipients

I have some code for doing multiple email recipients.  You want something like this snippet inserted in your code:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set rng = Range("B2:H2")

For Each cel In rng.Cells
    OutMail.Recipients.Add (cel.Value)
Next cel

With OutMail
     .subject = subject
     .body = body
     '.Attachments.Add ("") 'You can add files here
     .Display
     '.Send
End With
```

I'm assuming that B2:H2 have valid email addresses in them.  In my code, I will set To;Cc;Bcc using 1;2;3 integer assignments in adjacent cells to the email addresses (let's assume B3:H3 for a moment), and in that case my `For Each` loop would look like this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim myRecipient As Object

Set rng = Range("B2:H2")

For Each cel In rng.Cells
    Set myRecipient = OutMail.Recipients.Add(cel.Value)
    myRecipient.Type = cel.Offset(1, 0).Value  'You can use an adjacent cell to assign To; Cc; or Bcc with 1; 2; or 3
Next cel

With OutMail
     .subject = subject
     .body = body
     '.Attachments.Add ("") 'You can add files here
     .Display
     '.Send
End With
```

Sorry, but I can't help you with the font formatting.