# Mail excel rows to each person in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, but I'm trying.(-:

I have found [this code](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail8.htm), which is working wonderfully except for two problems: 
 1. I have to manually change the range each time I want to use it.
 2. The emails aren't sent automatically. I have to hit "Send" on each 'new mail' window, and there are over a hundred windows...

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Inbar.

Comment: In what format are you sending the data to the schools?  A spreadsheet?  If so, create a `For...Next` loop that checks for a school name and copy's that entire row to a new sheet with the same name as the school email.  I'll post some sample ideas in an answer.

Comment: this should help you add multiple recipients to an email: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019651/automated-email-generation-not-resolving-multiple-recipients/13019972#13019972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASSUMES SCHOOL NAME IS COLUMN "E"  This macro will copy each row into a new sheet which will be created and named as a school name using the school_name in column E.  You would then have to e-mail each sheet to the respective school (which could be automated in a separate macro.

EDIT: Fixed code and tested working:

```
Sub SortKids()

Dim CurRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NameTest As String, NameStr As String
Dim DestRow As Long
Dim NewWS As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

LastRow = Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheets("Master").Range("E" & CurRow).Value = "" Then
        NameStr = "Error"
    Else
        NameStr = Sheets("Master").Range("E" & CurRow).Value
    End If
    NameTest = Worksheets(NameStr).Name
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Else
        Err.Clear
        Set NewWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            NewWS.Name = NameStr
        Sheets("Master").Rows(1).Copy
        Sheets(NameStr).Rows(1).PasteSpecial
    End If
    DestRow = Sheets(NameStr).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Master").Rows(CurRow).Copy
    Sheets(NameStr).Rows(DestRow).PasteSpecial
Next CurRow

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Even better. Thank you!

Comment: @Inbar I am doing some debugging on this code now.  I will update it shortly.  It is returning an error.